# How can I keep a parent folder path to load multiple xml files and images from different subfolders in flask python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, xml, flask, fetch-api

I ran into some trouble with parent folder paths in flask. From given folder structures with containing xml and image files, I want to build a web-app containing a menu and content section. Each page should load in a new browser tab, so that one can visit multiple pages with menu and content layout.

I have multiple folders, one parent folder with subfolders containing xml and image files like this:

[image]

I'm not allowed to change this folder structure and I had stored it in an upload folder named 'data'.
The xml file from folder1 is a menu that contains links to the content xml files placed in folder2.
All images and pdf files are stored in folder3.
I use the JavaScript Fetch API for sending the path to a flask route like this:

```
// fetch path_xml
async function fetchPMC(path_xml) {
  const url = "/menu"; // the flask route
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(path_xml),
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = await response.json();
    const w = window.open("menu"); // opens a new tab from menu route
    w.onload = function () {
      // load the menu content first! prevents an empty page
      pmcmenu = w.document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML =
        data["menu"]; // outputs menu HTML in DIV Container 'menu'
      sessionStorage.setItem("localmenu", menu); // browser storage for keeping data in a tab 
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

```py
from lxml import etree as ET

@app.route("/menu", methods=['POST'])
def menu():
    if request.method == 'POST':       
        data = request.json  # folder1 xml menu path
    # lxml parses html string for menu here (not shown)
    return {'menu': menu}  # this goes to the DIV container 'menu'
```

I did the same with the folder2 content. If I click on a hyperlink from the created menu, the JavaScript Fetch API sends the link to a flask route. After parsing it to a string which contains HTML, I use RegEx to extract the parent folder path from the json request and use a key-value mapping to replace the given image src with the present folder path:

```py
from lxml import etree as ET
import re

@app.route("/content", methods=['POST'])
def content():
    if request.method == 'POST':       
        path = request.json  # path to folder2 xml content
    # lxml parsing to html content here, to complex to show
    path = re.search(r'([^/]*?/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/)', dmc_path).group()  # extracts parent folder from requested path
        mapping = {'img/': f'{path}img/', 'pdf/': f'{path}pdf/'}
        for key, value in mapping.items(): 
            dmc_link = dmc_link.replace(key, value)  # replace key with the value
    return {'content': content} # this goes to the DIV container 'content'
```

It works, but obviously, it's a clunky workaround and not a very satisfying solution.
I wonder if there's a more accurate solution.
**I would like to fetch the xml menu, the xml content and the images in the same flask route, so that I can use the same parent folder path without the tricky RegEx and key-value mapping stuff. How can I achieve this?**

Comment: What specific part do you need help with?

Comment: I would like to fetch the xml menu, the xml content and the images in the same flask route, so that I can use the same parent folder path without the tricky RegEx and key-value mapping stuff.